# A torus bundle whose vertical tangent bundle is indecomposable

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I would like to see an example of a fiber bundle $\mathbb{T}^2 \to X \xrightarrow{\pi}  B$ whose fibers are tori $\mathbb{T}^2:=(S^1)^2$ and whose vertical tangent bundle $\ker(d\pi) \to X$ is not decomposable? Which homotopy groups does one need to look at to construct such an example?

(This problem has been edited using inputs from the comments.)

Comment: I can suggest looking at first homotopy group of a base. Take any nontrivial 2-dimensional local system $L$ on $B$. Bundle with the fiber $(L \otimes \Bbb R)/L$ is of the form you want.

Comment: What is $P$ here?

Comment: R. van Dobben de Bruyn, The $P$ was a typo, thanks for noticing.

Comment: If $K$ denotes the Klein bottle, then $S^1\to K \xrightarrow{p} S^1$ and $\ker dp$ is non-trivial. So $T^2 \to S^1\times K \xrightarrow{\pi} S^1$ where $\pi(x, y) = p(y)$ and $\ker d\pi \cong \varepsilon^1\oplus\ker dp$ which is again non-trivial.

Comment: Michael Albanese, I corrected the question based on your example. What I am really looking for is that the directions in the torus mix.

Comment: I suspect any 2-torus bundle over the circle with monodromy an Anosov matrix (eg ((2,1),(1,1))) will give you what you want.

Comment: @HJRW  The Anosov matrix has irrational eigenvectors, and these give a trivialization of the tangent space. In your example, the eigenvectors are $(1,(-1 \pm \sqrt{5})/2)$

Comment: Thanks. I guess I don’t know exactly what you mean by “decomposable”. One could instead choose a base with fundamental group the closed surface of genus 2, and get it to act on the torus by a pair of matrices that cannot be simultaneously diagonalised. Would that give you what you want?

Comment: Another possibility is to use the monodromy matrix ((1,1),(0,1)). This, of course, is reducible but not decomposable.

Comment: @HJRW by indecomposable, I mean that a real vector bundle $E \to X$ does not split into a direct sum $E_1 +E_2$ of real vector bundles on $X$. An example of an indecomposable bundle on $\mathbb P^1$ is $\mathcal O(1)$ viewed as a real bundle of rank two. Infact for a rank two bundle the obstruction to decomposition lies in $O(2)/(O(1) \times O(1)) \simeq S^1$ and this is equivalent to a second cohomology class vanishing.

Comment: Then I think either of the latter two examples I suggested should work, shouldn't they? I'm not sure about the cohomological characterisation, but surely it should imply that the monodromy is decomposable, since the exponential map will identify the vertical tangent bundle with the universal cover of the torus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $T=\{(z_0,z_1,z_2)\in(S^1)^3:z_0z_1z_2=1\}$, so $T$ is homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$ and has an obvious action of the symmetric group $\Sigma_3$.  The action of $\Sigma_3$ on $H_1(T;\mathbb{R})$ is indecomposable, and this homology group can also be identified with the tangent space to $T$ at the identity element.

Now put $F=\{(u_0,u_1,u_2)\in\mathbb{C}^3:u_i\neq u_j\text{ for } i\neq j\}$.  This also has a natural action of $\Sigma_3$, which is free.  Put $E=(T\times F)/\Sigma_3$ and $B=F/\Sigma_3$, so we have a fibre bundle $T\to E\to B$.  This will have the required indecomposability.  Note that the identity element of $T$ gives a section of the projection $E\to B$.

The cohomology of $F$ is a well-known example.  For $i\neq j$ we can define $\pi_{ij}\colon F\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ by $\pi_{ij}(z)=z_j-z_i$, and by pulling back the generator of $H^1(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})$ we get an element $a_{ij}\in H^1(F)$.  These satisfy $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and $a_{ij}^2=0$ and the Arnol'd relation $a_{ij}a_{jk}+a_{jk}a_{ki}+a_{ki}a_{ij}=0$.  It follows that $\{1,a_{01},a_{02},a_{12},a_{01}a_{02},a_{01}a_{12}\}$ is a basis for $H^*(F)$.  From this description you can calculate $H^*(B)$ and $H^*(E)$ using the Serre spectral sequence.  With rational coefficients this just degenerates to $H^*(B;\mathbb{Q})=H^*(F;\mathbb{Q})^{\Sigma_3}=\mathbb{Q}$ and $H^*(E;\mathbb{Q})=H^*(T\times F;\mathbb{Q})^{\Sigma_3}$.  It can't be too hard to calculate that last ring explicitly, but I have not done so.

If you prefer to work with homotopy groups, it is standard that $\pi_1(B)$ is the braid group $Br_3$.  This has a standard surjective homomorphism to $\Sigma_3$, whose kernel is the pure braid group $PBr_3$, which can be identified with $\pi_1(F)$.  It is also known that $\pi_i(F)=\pi_i(B)=\pi_i(T)=0$ for $i>1$.  The map $PBr_3\to\Sigma_3$ gives an action of $PBr_3$ on $\pi_1(T)\simeq\mathbb{Z}^2$, using which we can form the semidirect product $PBr_3\ltimes\mathbb{Z}^2$.  Using the split fibre bundle $T\to E\to B$ we can identify $\pi_1(E)$ with this semidirect product, and also see that $\pi_i(E)=0$ for $i>1$.